# Procedurally generate seamless fractal noise textures

Tags: c++, opengl, noise, fractals, procedural-generation

I have been generating noise textures to use as height maps for terrain generation. In this application, initially there is a 256x256 noise texture that is used to create a block of land that the user is free to roam around. When the user reaches a certain boundary in-game the application generates a new texture and thus another block of terrain.

In the code, a table of 64x64 random values are generated, and the values in the texture are the result of interpolating between these points at various 'frequencies' and 'wavelengths' using a smoothstep function, and then combined to form the final noise texture; and finally the values in the texture are divided through by its largest value to effectively normalize it. When the player is at the boundary and a new texture is created, the random number table that is created re-uses the values from the appropriate edge of the previous texture (eg. if the new texture is for a block of land that is on the +X side of the previous one, the last value in every row of the previous texture is used as the first value in every row of random numbers in the next.)

My problem is this: even though the same values are being used across the edges of adjacent textures, they are nowhere near seamless - some neighboring points on the terrain are mismatched by many many metres. My guess is that the changing frequencies that are used to sample the random number table are probably having a significant effect on all areas of the texture. So how might one generate fractal noise poceduraly, ie. as needed, AND have it look continuous with adjacent values?

Here is a section of the code that returns a value interpolated between the points on the random number table given a point P:

```
float MainApp::assessVal(glm::vec2 P){
//Integer component of P
int xi = (int)P.x;
int yi = (int)P.y;

//Decimal component ofP
float xr = P.x - xi;
float yr = P.y - yi;

//Find the grid square P lies inside of
int x0 = xi % randX;
int x1 = (xi + 1) % randX;
int y0 = yi % randY;
int y1 = (yi + 1) % randY;


//Get random values for the 4 nodes
float r00 = randNodes->randNodes[y0][x0];
float r10 = randNodes->randNodes[y0][x1];
float r01 = randNodes->randNodes[y1][x0];
float r11 = randNodes->randNodes[y1][x1];

//Smoother interpolation so
//texture appears less blocky
float sx = smoothstep(xr);
float sy = smoothstep(yr);

//Find the weighted value of the 4
//random values. This will be the
//final value in the noise texture
float sx0 = mix(r00, r10, sx);
float sx1 = mix(r01, r11, sx);

return mix(sx0, sx1, sy);
}
```

Where randNodes is a 2 dimensional array containing the random values.

And here is the code that takes all the values returned from the above function and constructs texture data:

```
 int layers = 5;
float wavelength = 1, frequency = 1;

for (int k = 0; k < layers; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < stepsY; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < stepsX; j++){
            //Compute value for (stepsX * stepsY) interpolation points
            //across the grid of random numbers
            glm::vec2 P = glm::vec2((float)j/stepsX * randX, (float)i/stepsY * randY);
            buf[i * stepsY + j] += assessVal(P * wavelength) * frequency;
        }
    }
    //repeat (layers) times with different signals
    wavelength *= 0.5;
    frequency *= 2;
}

for(int i = 0; i < buf.size(); i++){
    //divide all data by the largest value.
    //this normalises the data to avoid saturation
    buf[i] /= largestVal;
}
```

Finally, here is an example of two textures generated by these functions that *should* be seamless, but aren't:

[image] [image]

The 2 images placed side by side as they are now are obviously mis-matched.

Comment: Is there a reason you do it all yourself instead of using an existing solution like e.g. [libnoise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm aware there are libraries out there, however It's just a preference of mine to write most of my code from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Your code wraps the values only in the domain of the noise texture you read from, but not in the domain of the texture being generated.

For the texture T of size `stepX` to be repeatable (let's consider 1-d case for simplicity) you must have

```
T(0) == T(stepX)
```

Or in your case (substitute `j = 0` and `j = stepX`):

```
assessVal(0) == assessVal(randX * wavelength)
```

For when `k >= 1` this is clearly not true in your code, because

```
(randX / pow(2, k)) % randX != 0
```

One solution is to decrease `randX` and `randY` while you go up the frequencies.

But my typical approach would rather be starting from a `2x2` random texture, upscale it to `4x4` with `GL_REPEAT`, add a bit more per-pixel noise, continue upscaling to `8x8` etc.. till I get to the desired size.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but if i decrease 'randX' and 'randY' by say a factor of 0.5 every time k increases, will that not be equivalent to the sampling rate of the first pass where 'wavelength' and 'frequency' both equal one? I find that when I run this code the texture produced looks blocky as though there has only been one pass. Also, if I used the technique you describe at the end of your post, would that not cause the texture to change every time I expanded it? Once a texture is generated it must remain as is in this application. Perhaps I'm missing the point here.

Comment: Sorry, I think that I misunderstood your question. Do you mean that the two images you posted are of adjacent tiles that should match continuously? But then the code you posted must be incomplete, because it doesn't account for **which** tile you're currently generating. Can you post a complete self-contained code?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, those 2 tiles placed side by side should be seamless, eg. the rightmost edge of the 1st tile should be about the same as the leftmost edge of the second. The rest of the code is trivial/irrelevant, but basically a table called randNodes[64][64] is filled with random numbers for the first tile, and the second tile's randNodes[64][64] is filled with newly generated random numbers except for at [ j ][0] where 0 <= j < randY (the left 'edge' of the random number table.)

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of course is that your smoothing changes pixels to match their neighbors, but you later add new neighbors and do not re-smooth the pixels who got new neighbors.

One simple and common workaround is to keep an edge of invisible pixels, the width of which is half that of your smoothing kernel. Now, when expanding the area, you *can* resmooth those invisible pixels just before they're revealed. Don't forget to add a new edge of invisible pixels!

Comment: What are you referring to when you say 're-smooth?' So if I built a texture 1.5 times the size of what is being used to display the terrain, and then I use that extra half of the first texture in the second texture but then add more random nodes, your'e saying that second texture will still be seamless with the first? It seems that if I call 'assessVal()' on the points within say x = 0 to x = wid/2 for the second texture, after adding more nodes, it would end up quite similar to how it is now.  Or am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, I understood you already smoothed. Anyway, a simple smoothing would be to replace each pixel with 0.6 * its former value, plus 0.1 * the former value of its 4 neighbors. This greatly decreases abrupt steps, and therefore makes seams less noticable. In this simple case, the smoothing width is just one pixel. You can use larger neighborhoods to make the smoothing less obvious.